# Post Data to URL through Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, url, post

I'm trying to post data to URL by using Android App.

[URL](http://comparch2011.appspot.com/):

parameters:
"name" and "message"

I use the following code but it doesn't work:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://comparch2011.appspot.com/");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "DEV"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "AndDev is Cool!"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
     }
```

Comment: Where is it failing? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: when i run the app there is a message appear:                Unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: And the message says what? Try looking in LogCat for erros and post them here...

Comment: you are running network task in main thread use async task instead now what you are getting is an ANR and is possibly due to that -- now its in a button click i hope

Comment: If your phone is plugged into the computer or you are using the emulator, you should look in LogCat and post it here.

Comment: can you please stop saying 'it doesn't work' and post your frelling stacktrace ?

Comment: @thomas How can i post the Logfile here it is now on drop box:https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8f0na1zvj8vo7z/log.txt?m

Comment: as per your log its due to the strict mode policy present in android 3.0+ switch to sync task for nw operations or use separate thread for the purpose (can be overcome d by avoiding strict mode -- but not recommended)

Comment: Yes, droidhot is right. see my answer below for further details with links to the docs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-first thing first : you should use [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html). It will give you real time logs of your phone on your computers, it is incredibly useful to know what is going on.

-I suspect that you are making these calls in an Activity and in this case the app is simply crashing because of that : their is a safeguard to prevent you from doing that. It raises errors 'network on main thread' when necessary (like here).
The problem is that Activities are ran on the main thread, the one that is also used for the UI. so when you make such a network call, all the UI is blocked until the function has returned (and since it is waiting for the website to respond it can take a couple of seconds, which is very bad for the usability of your app).

The solution is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) . It is an easy to use class that will allow you to make asynchronous calls (ie calls that don't block the UI).

Comment: you are welcome :-)  . It must be the most common error that everyone does at least once. It's is a good thing that by default the app crashes when you use the network in the UI thread, that way you can learn why you should not do it and use an asynchronous call instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your LogCat, the error is a NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Which Android states here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html as:

### NetworkOnMainThreadException:

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its     main thread.
>        This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to
>   do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

So take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html instead, and be aware that the getResponse not should be called on the UI thread.

Alternatively you can probably just change the target or change the strictpolicy as follows, but I would no suggest doing so...

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't perform Network activities on the main thread. Because it doesn't allow the user to respond to the view when the network action is being performed.

Use an Asynctask, and it will work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Nithin